# Wrap text on Cell FPDF with MultiCell

Tags: php, fpdf, word-wrap

The problem is when I create a MultiCell, the last Cell drops down and the line breaks.
An example is:

1 | 2 | 3 | 4

1 | 2 | 3wrap |

4 |

This is my fpdf :

```
$pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['1'],'LR',0);
$pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['2'],'LR',0);

if($pdf->GetStringWidth($data['3']) > 65){
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
    $pdf->MultiCell(65,5,$data['3'],0,'LR',false);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
}else{
    $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['3'],'LR',0);
}
$pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['4'],'LR',true);
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap Text in Fpdf in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542244/wrap-text-in-fpdf-in-php)