# Word wrap in a cell in FPDF using PHP?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to print some words in a cell but **wordwrap in not working in a cell**, what should i do?

```
  $pdf->setXY(124, 36 + ($i * 5.1));
            $pdf->SetFillColor(238, 236, 225);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8); 
            $pdf->Cell(40, 6, $resultArrayIndex['pubtitle'], 0, 0, 'L', True);
```

Here is my output - [image: words are flowing outside cell]

and here what i am trying to achieve - [image] trying to wrap word within a cell. (Any help or hint is appreciated)

**Edited after comments and sugggestions**

After all u suggesting  me use Multicell, I used it but it's still not helpful
not equal gap with each multicell and even sometimes it's uneven size text and gap

[image]

**My code after your suggestion and i am using it in for-loop**

```
    $pdf->setXY(17, 36+($i * 6.9));
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
            $pdf->MultiCell(19, 4.6, formatPubDate($resultArrayIndex['pubdate']), 1);

            $pdf->setXY(42, 36 + ($i * 6.9)); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
            $pdf->MultiCell(50.5, 4.6, ($resultArrayIndex['title']), 1);

            $pdf->setXY(124, 33.7 + ($i * 9.0)); 
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8); 
            $pdf-> MultiCell(27, 2.9 , $resultArrayIndex['pubtitle'],1);
```

Comment: have you tried $pdf->MultiCell(40, 6, $resultArrayIndex['pubtitle'], 0, 'L', True); ? find more help http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm

Comment: I tried it's not working, is there any function or way to do it smartly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrap Text in Fpdf in Php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542244/wrap-text-in-fpdf-in-php)

Comment: Check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477372/make-text-wrap-in-a-cell-with-fpdf

Comment: I update my question please check again